# NOOBS Where is Config File

Tags: software-installation

I am on a windows PC and would like to edit config.txt. However I do not see it anywhere. I tried showing hidden files and folders and even told it to show system files, all to no avail. 
This is what my NOOBS folder looks like this:
[image]

os is empty and defaults has a subfolder called slides which has a raspberry logo png. Any ideas? Disregard binary showing up as a media player file...I haven't fixed that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOOBS is just an easy installer for a selection of OS (like Raspbian, RaspBMC and others) and not an OS itself. But config.txt is part of your selected OS, e.g. for Raspbian it is in `/boot/config.txt`

Comment: So if I have a card preloaded with noobs, I still need to put Raspbian on there? Or does it get it from the internet when you select it?

Comment: No, NOOBS contains Raspbian, so all you have to do is inserting the NOODS card and start your Raspberry. Beware, NOOBS will be replaced by the chosen OS. You need an internet connection for updating Raspbian and installing additional packages, not 100% sure, but I think during the OS installation internet connection is not required.

Comment: If it contains it where is it in the noobs folder. Is it in binary in bootcode.bin or something? Once you answer I will upvote question.

Comment: No, it's not in the NOOBS folder, it will be on your filesystem *after* you'll have installed an OS.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to "edit config.txt"? What are you hoping to achieve?

Follow the instructions for "First boot" on https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/

Following this config.txt will be on the OS boot partition, but you may not be able to see it on Windows, as I believe it does not support multiple partitions on SD.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might appear as a "hidden file" on windows so you might have to change the view settings in file manager to see hidden files.

Comment: The question specifically states that showing hidden files is already enabled.